# What is a hit die, and how do I calculate monster HP?

Tags: monsters, adnd-1e, hit-points

I'm new and have the AD&D Monster Manual and Fiend Folio. I want to know how to calculate monsters' HP. Does 4 hit dice mean 4 HP, or 4 rolls of a die, and how do I know what die to roll if it is?

Comment: I've edited your question to clarify it - please check to see if it's still asking what you meant to ask. Also, welcome to the site! Please check our [tour] to get an idea of how things work here, we're different to other sites.

Comment: Seriously? This is explained at the very start of the Monster Manual under "explanatory notes" on page 5! This is a "Can someone read the book to me because I can't be bothered" question.

Answer (score 6):

Hit dice in AD&D are d8 unless otherwise specified. A creature with 4 hit dice would have 4d8 hit points.  That means that you roll a d8 four times and add the results together to generate its hit points.

> **HIT DICE** indicates the parameters of the number of hit points a creature can withstand before being killed. Unless stated otherwise hit dice are 8-sided (1-8 hit points). The indicated number of dice are rolled, and the numbers shown on each are added together to arrive at a total number of hit points. (MM1e p.5)

Comment: I brought in the citation you mentioned--feel free to trim it back; I figured it'd be easier for you to cut than to add.